# How to populate AlertDialog with RecyclerView items

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-alertdialog

I'm a beginner in android programming. I created a recyclerview and it displays items from MySQL database. But I would like these items to be displayed inside the alert dialog rather than in the fragment. I have no idea how to do that.

here is the code I have:

```
public class profileFragment extends Fragment implements SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener {

    private SpotsAdapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private ArrayList<Spots> spotsList;
    private Context context;
    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeLayout;
    private int refresh_count =0;
    private TextView TVspot;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile, container, false);
        swipeLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh_layout);
        swipeLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);

        context = view.getContext();

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull final View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);



        spotsList = new ArrayList<Spots>();

        recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.recy);
        LinearLayoutManager lm = new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        lm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lm);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        Api api = RetrofitClient.getREtrofit().create(Api.class);
        Call<ArrayList<Spots>> call = api.getSpotslList();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Spots>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<ArrayList<Spots>> call, Response<ArrayList<Spots>> response) {
                spotsList = response.body();
                Log.e("REsult", (spotsList.get(0)).toString());
                adapter = new SpotsAdapter(spotsList, context);


                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.e("sid", adapter.valueOfSid());
                TVspot= view.findViewById(R.id.parkingTV);
                TVspot.setText("Your parking spot is:" + adapter.valueOfSid());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<ArrayList<Spots>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("FAil", String.valueOf(t.toString()));
            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public void onRefresh() {

        swipeLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        Api api = RetrofitClient.getREtrofit().create(Api.class);
        Call<ArrayList<Spots>> call = api.getSpotslList();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<Spots>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(retrofit2.Call<ArrayList<Spots>> call, Response<ArrayList<Spots>> response) {
                spotsList = response.body();
                Log.e("REsult", String.valueOf(spotsList.size()));
                adapter = new SpotsAdapter(spotsList, context);

                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                TVspot.setText("Your parking spot is:" + adapter.valueOfSid());
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(retrofit2.Call<ArrayList<Spots>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("FAil", String.valueOf(t.toString()));
            }
        });

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.e("FAil", String.valueOf(spotsList.size()));


    }
}
```

any help and suggestions on how to put the recyclerview elements inside an alertdialog would be highly appreciated.

Comment: This is easily doable, you need to use `DialogFragment` class and use a custom layout inside it. The official document is sufficient https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs#CustomLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom dialog by extending DialogFragment to your custom class.
You can refer this [link](https://camposha.info/course/android-fragment/lesson/android-dialogfragment-show-recyclerview/)

Dismiss from Adapter class

Inside Adapter class Define an interface..

```
public interface ClickListener{
     void onClickDismiss();
}
```

Create ClickListener Object and assign instance of DialogFragment to this Object inside your Constructor

```
ClickListener clickListner = (ClickListner) dialogFragmentInstance;
```

Inside OnbindViewHolder methods onclickListner of your recyclerview item add this code to call the interface method.

```
clickListner.onClickDismiss();
```

Inside DialogFragment Class

```
 class YourDialog extends DialogFragment implements Adapter.ClickListener{
    ......

    @Override
    public void onClickDismiss(){
    dismiss();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! but how do I setArgument() to data from recyclerView?

Comment: I did not get your question ,can you please clarify it? What do you mean by setArgument()

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work! Do you know how can I make the dialog close after I choose an item?

Comment: Yes, you have to declare an interface inside Adapter class and then implement it in DialogFragment. When ever button clicks call the interface method . Inside override method you can dismiss the Dialog.